# Passing 2D arrays pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference, 2d

There are a lot of questions on this topic, but none seems to answer my question: 
 - I want to build a sort of "array or array", like a matrix. This is my example case

```
int A[Things][Elements];
int B[Things][Elements];
int C[Things][Elements];

for (uint8_t i=0; i < Things; i++)
    myFunct(C[i], A[i], B[i], ....);

/******************/
/***** Where: *****/

void myFunct(int *O, int* iA, int* iB, ....)
{
    for (uint8_t j=0; j < Elements; j++)
        O[j] = iA[j] + iB[j];
}
```

I know the code above has no sense, but it's just a super simple example of what I'm trying to do.
While I was testing I saw that the first one (i=0) is done correctly, then the next ones (i>0) are wrong.
I probably made a mistake in the definition of the inputs of myFunct(), but I can't understand what. I know I can do the `i*Elements + j` and play with pointers, but I would like to have a more readable code for once.

Thanks for the answers,
Ev3.

Comment: Hmm... This code seem OK, provided `Things` and `Elements` are true constants (`#define`). Said differently, this is the reason why we insist in having [mcve]: the problem is likely to be in the part you have not shown...

Comment: Yes, they are defined with #define. Knowing that the code was correct and wasn't a problem of pointers usage, I went through a deep debug session and found out that the problem was due to a (unfortunate and rare) coincidence in float division approximation. Thanks for your answer